# Can we play prerecorded message in a call through iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I want to create an iPhone app with following features:

1. User should be able to make a call to number.
2. App will play the prerecorded message when call get connected.
3. After playing the message, line will be connected and user will be able to communicate with the person to whom he made the call.

I heard that Apple doesn't allow the developers to interact with the calling functionality of iPhone but is there any way to achieve this. Please suggest!

Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have heard correctly, According to Apple Developer Library, it is `not possible to intercept` the calling functionality.

Simple Apple does not allow such stuff with current sdk.

Not so sure but, May be possible for jailbroken iPhone app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jennis! But is there any way to achieve this? I mean can it be done using server side programming or by using third party calling service like [Called In](http://called.in/api/about/playback/)?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround is to redirect your call in a call center like 3CX , into a virtual number that is predefined to work as digital receptionist and has one virtual number, "your internal number", you will need to download the app for iPhone and register that internal number to your iPhone, that way the app will ring on your iPhone 3cx app and the client will listen your DR message meanwhile.!!!

Keep in mind redirected calls may have some extra charges, you will have to clarify them with your provider.

A more clear approach is to have your clients call direct your business line where they can listen a pre recorded msg and have your internal number in your mobile phone!